# Can't connect to CRAN mirror from RStudio

Tags: r, cran

This is my first post in the stack though this has been my go to option for any coding related issue for a long time. So recently my machine was reconfigured and I had to reinstall with the IT support all my IDEs including R and RStudio. Since then I am getting this vexing issue of installing any new R package and even existing R packages keep throwing error that it's not installed or can't connect to CRAN mirror

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "H:/My Documents/R/R-3.3.2"         "H:/My Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library" "C:/R/R-3.5.3/library"             
> .libPaths("C:/R/R-3.5.3/library")
> install.packages("DBI",repos="https://cran.rstudio.com/")
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘DBI’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
```

I saw this was posted in another thread here: 
[R - cannot access urls for package installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931342/r-cannot-access-urls-for-package-installation)

I tried all recommendations in here, still couldn't get it fixed. Any idea what else could be broken. Much appreciate your reponse. BTW, I am not an R pro either, just a little bit hands on.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using just `install.packages("DBI")`?  ie, using the default `repos`?  Is it just this `repos` that's giving you problems, or all of them?

Comment: Try another mirror, or look into whether you have any online restrictions from your machine.

Comment: Yeah I tried all of that, explicit setting the repos.. no better