Trouble installing packages in R
I just downloaded R and Rstudio to try to learn it, but I am unable to install the tidyverse package. I've tried install.packages("tidyverse") and install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies=TRUE, type="win.binary"). The error that keeps showing up is:
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/DBI_1.2.2.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/DBI_1.2.2.zip': status was 'SSL connect error'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/DBI_1.2.2.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
download of package ‘DBI’ failed

This is happening for all other dependencies and tidyverse itself. I've also tried using the Rstudio menu for installing packages and that hasn't worked either, the same error appears. Additionally, on occasion 1-5 dependencies will work and display:
package ‘googlesheets4’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've scoured other forums for answers to no avail.
Update
I am running windows with the latest version of R and Rstudio. I tried using my phones hotspot and a bunch of the dependencies were throwing a different error:
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/rlang_1.1.3.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/rlang_1.1.3.zip': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/rlang_1.1.3.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘rlang’ failed

I also noticed that 'tidyverse.zip' was 'successfully unpacked and sums checked', but when I tried loading the library it threw this:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: library(pkg, lib.loc = loc, character.only = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
  error: there is no package called ‘ggplot2’

Hopefully the additional info helps!

Maybe this post can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931342/r-cannot-access-urls-for-package-installation

What operating system and version are you using? Can you access https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/DBI_1.2.2.zip from a web browser? Is it possible you are on a network that is blocking the connection?

@MrFlick see edits. I think the network may have casued the SSL error but now there's something new lol

@Cath Thanks! I went down a rabbit hole in that direction and it helped a lot!

The tidyverse package is really just a meta-package that auto loads functions from a bunch of different packages. If you are missing a dependency, then you'll need to install those. If ggplot2 is not present, run install.packages("ggplot2")
